How to avoid deeply nested if-else in JavaScript with different, computationally expensive condition variables?
I'm writing codes to find a proper target and make subsequent operation on it. My current codes would first try to look for Type 1. If it doesn't exist, I'll try to look for Type 2 and so on. Because the find function costs CPU too much, I'd like to avoid using it to find all Types at the beginning. The following are my current codes. How can I simplify them?
const target1 = find1(Type1);
if(target1){
    operate1(target1);
}else{

    const target2 = find2(Type2);
    if(target2){
        operate2(target2);
    }else{

        const target3 = find3(Type3);
        if(target3){
            operate3(target3);
        }else{
            ...
        }
    }
}        


https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp switch statement lets you check for different cases and execute the code accordingly

@Mr.Irrelevant For switch statement you need to have single value to compare, that's not the case.

There's nothing really wrong with the code you already have. If your "find" operations are using "too much CPU", your time would be better spent improving their performance. Perhaps you can use a single combined "find" operation to do the work and return an indication of what kind of result was found.

please add the type of targetN.

Use some() operator.

The some() method is an iterative method. It calls a provided callbackFn function once for each element in an array, until the callbackFn returns a truthy value. If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true and stops iterating through the array.

Combining Wimanicesir and Oleksandr answers, you can use a single evaluation function.
const operations = [
    { find: find1, operate: operate1, type: Type1 },
    { find: find2, operate: operate2, type: Type2 },
    { find: find3, operate: operate3, type: Type3 },
    // Add more operations as needed
];

function findAndOperate({ find, operate, type }) {
    const target = find(type);
    if (target) {
        operate(target);
        return true; // Target found and operated on
    }
    return false; // Target not found
}

let targetFound = operations.some(findAndOperate);

if (!targetFound) {
    console.error('No target found');
}


You can move this code to separate function and utilize early return:
function findTarget()
{
    const target1 = find1(Type1);

    if(target1){
        operate1(target1);

        return;
    }

    const target2 = find2(Type2);

    if(target2){
        operate2(target2);

        return;
    }

    const target3 = find3(Type3);

    if(target3){
        operate3(target3);

        return;
    }

    ...
}


Or if your variables/functions are really named that way, use simple loop:
for (let i = 1; i <= possibleTypes; i++) {
    let target = window['find' + i](window['Type' + i])

    if (!target) {
        continue;
    }

    window['operate' + i](target);

    break;
}


The first option with function and early return is the clearest and easiest to read among all the answers. That's how I would write it.

@André Yes, that's how we are doing it in our project, expecially good when there is lots of different logic/conditions

Create an object with all params.
Loop and break if found.
const targets = [
    { type: Type1, find: find1, operate: operate1 },
    { type: Type2, find: find2, operate: operate2 },
    { type: Type3, find: find3, operate: operate3 },
    // Add more types as needed
];

let found = false;
for (const { type, find, operate } of targets) {
    const target = find(type);
    if (target) {
        operate(target);
        found = true;
        break; // Exit loop if target is found
    }
}

if (!found) {
    // Handle case when no target is found
    console.log("No target found");
}


Since the find and operate tasks come as sequence with an early exit at the first successfully finished find and operate block, one can provide an array of such tasks to a function which will operate said array via  e.g. the some method where the latter gets used for exiting early.
The trick of mapping the client's problem as to be sequentially processed tasks has the advantage that the solution can be run with just one or up to a finite number of "find and operate" tasks, which the following provided example code is going to prove ...
function findAndOperateTarget(tasks) {
  let target;

  tasks
    .some(({ type, find, operate }) => {
      let success = false;

      target = find(type);

      if (target) {
        success = true;

        operate(target);
      }
      return success;
    });

  return target;
}

const target = findAndOperateTarget([
  { type: Type1, find: find1, operate: operate1 },
  { type: Type2, find: find2, operate: operate2 },
  { type: Type3, find: find3, operate: operate3 },
]);


You could wrap the value in an object and the logic as well and call it until you got a truthy value for at a step, like here for value 2.
Usage:
take(type).if(find)?.then(operate)



const
    take = value => ({
        value,
        if(f) {
            console.log('if value: ' + this.value);
            const value = f(this.value);
            if (value) return take(value);
        },
        then(f) {
            console.log('do value: ' + this.value);
            f(this.value);
            return true;
        }
    });

take(1).if(v => false)?.then(value => console.log(value))
    || take(2).if(v => 10 * v)?.then(value => console.log(value))
    || take(3).if(v => 11 * v)?.then(value => console.log(value));




Try creating a list of checks and looping through them.
This will remove nesting, but adds a loop.
const procedures = [
  procedure1,
  procedure2,
  procedure3,
  () => {
    console.log("nothing...");
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < procedures.length; i++) {
  if (procedures[i]()) break; // stop if procedure is done
}

function procedure1() {
  const target1 = find1(Type1);

  if (target1) {
    operate1(target1);

    return true; // notify that procedure is done
  }
}

function procedure2() {
  const target2 = find2(Type2);

  if (target2) {
    const res = operate2(target2);

    if (res === null) return false; // continue with next procedure

    // notify that procedure is done
    return true;
  }
}

function procedure3() {
  const target3 = find2(Type3);

  if (target3) {
    const res = operate3(target3);

    return true;
  }
}



You can use early return pattern to avoid deeply nested if-else conditions.
In your case, you can do something like this.
const target1 = find1(Type1);
if (target1) {
  operate1(target1);
  return;
}

const target2 = find2(Type2);
if (target2) {
  operate2(target2);
  return;
}

const target3 = find3(Type3);
if (target3) {
  operate3(target3);
  return;
}

OR this (based on the context)
const target1 = find1(Type1);
if (!target1) {
  return;
}
operate1(target1);

const target2 = find2(Type2);
if (!target2) {
  return;
}
operate2(target2);

const target3 = find3(Type3);
if (!target3) {
  return;
}
operate3(target3);

Additionally, if you use ESLint, you can add this ESLint rule https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-else-return. This is an auto-fixable rule, so most of your code will automatically be migrated to make use of early return using --fix.

Your second example will find correct target and will try to find next target as if previous has failed to be found.
